# Visual Studio 2010 deployment script creates objects in wrong order - trigger after stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, deployment, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I created a view that selects from multiple tables in a complex query.

- Due to the complexity, I created insert/update/delete INSTEAD OF triggers to handle these operations on the view.
- I also created stored procedures that update the view.

When I build the VS2010 database project, the SQL script contains the CREATE commands in this order: (1) the view, (2) the stored procedures, and then (3) the triggers.

Now, when I run the deployment script, I get an error:

```
*** SQL01268    D:\scripts\vs2010\Database.sql (28494,0).Net SqlClient Data Provider:
Msg 4405, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MyViewSave, Line 18 View or function 'MyView' is
not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables
```

If the triggers would be created before the stored procedure, there would be no problem.

How can I make sure the triggers are created before the stored procedures?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have run into a known issue with Visual Studio 2010:

- [Connect request](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/623264/dependency-issues-not-handled-correctly-in-database-projects)
- [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122678/vs2010-database-project-deployment-database-objects-build-order)
- [MSDN forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/3ae858f0-894a-4a38-84c8-5adc2d9236d2)

That said, [Microsoft recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833270.aspx#DependenciesAndUpdateScripts) you help Visual Studio detect the object dependencies it seems to be ignoring in its deployment script by:

> schema-qualify[ing] the names of objects that are involved in dependent relationships.

So if everything you are developing sits in the `dbo` schema, make sure to prepend the proc and view names giving you trouble with their schema name.  For example: `dbo.MyView` instead of just `MyView`. Visual Studio has a "Fully Qualify Name" feature under the Refactor menu when you right-click on an object that'll help you do that very quickly.

If that doesn't help, give Google a spin and take a look at some of the workarounds suggested on the pages linked above. Let us know what ended up working for you.